# Loop Through XML Parse Function and Display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cordova, xml-parsing

I have a function that at the moment displays the hard-coded XML data in an iPhone app;

```
    function viewXMLFiles() {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "TestInfo.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

        document.getElementById("docname").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("filetype").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file_type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("fileloc").innerHTML = pathToRoot + "/" + document.getElementById("docname").innerHTML;

        document.getElementById("docname1").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document_name")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("filetype1").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("file_type")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("fileloc1").innerHTML = pathToRoot + "/" + document.getElementById("docname1").innerHTML;
    }
```

and i want to put it into a loop so when i add the option to upload files the file will automatically loop through and display the data when a button is clicked instead of having to change the code. the button is coded as such;

```
<button onclick = "viewXMLFiles(); document.getElementById('showDocumentLink').style.display = 'block';">View Document Info</button><br>
```

and the page is set out as such to load the XML into it;

```
    <div id = "doclist">
        <h2>Document 1;</h2>
        <label>Document Name;</label><br><span id = "docname"></span><br>
        <label>File Type</label><br><span id = "filetype"></span><br>
        <label>File Location</label><br><span id = "fileloc"></span><br>
    </div>

    <div id = "doclist">
        <h2>Document 2;</h2>
        <label>Document Name;</label><br><span id = "docname1"></span><br>
        <label>File Type</label><br><span id = "filetype1"></span><br>
        <label>File Location</label><br><span id = "fileloc1"></span><br>
    </div>
```

I'm really new to XML files and how to Parse them using JavaScript, so any help in showing  me how to put them correctly into a `for` loop would be great. I don't really have an idea of how to do it, so any help at all would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "document_name" );
$("#docname").append($title.text());
```

Comment: instead of what? or just add it where the `xmlDoc` is originally declared?

Comment: just parsing the xml file after parsing the xml file we can get the output easily.thats'y we using $.parseXML( xml ).